# datatales server side add class tr

Tags: datatables, addition, tr

how to add id to the specific td element? I want to color some tr element text to red, yellow and blue - if user expired add red text color, if expiring in next 2days add yellow and so on...

i im using server side php script to generate datatables data and then send using json.

here is what i ime getting from server side:

```
<tr class="gradeA odd" id="3650">
   <td class=" sorting_1">3650</td>
   <td class="">user234</td>
   <td class="">2013-12-28</td>
   <td class="">2014-01-28</td>
</tr>
```

i would like to get this:

```
<tr class="gradeA odd" id="3650">
   <td id="red" class=" sorting_1">3650</td>
   <td id="red" class="">user234</td>
   <td id="red" class="">2013-12-28</td>
   <td id="red" class="">2014-01-28</td>
</tr>
```

so how to add id on server-side.php here is that skript:
      http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

i im new to datatables and jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i figured it out....just need to read API for Datatables...here is solution if someone needs it...on server side php script i added row[5] for aadata witch contains value of expired days (0 to 5)...and then on clients side in datatables initialization using function fnCreatedRow i check value in aadata and if is 0 to 5 i apply css style color. here is the code:

```
  server side php:
  $row[12] = '5';


  clients side php:
  "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
                    if ( aData[12] == "5" )
                    {
                        // color rows from 0-6
                        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                            $('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).css( "color",  "#FFFF00" );
                        }
                    }
                }
```